# How do I get model binding not to stop after first failure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement well described errors in my WebApi if a request fails. When trying to bind a json body to a DTO class I get very nice readable errors for the first property where the model binding fails, but then it seems to stop. I want to return back information of all the fields where model binding failed.

My DTO class looks like the following:

```cs
public class RequestDTO
{
   public int FirstValue { get; set; }
   public int SecondValue { get; set; }
}
```

When passing in the following JSON

```cs
{
    "firstValue": "y",
    "secondValue": "x"
}
```

I get the following response

```cs
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|6ba7ef4a-442494fd16304f12.",
    "errors": {
        "$.firstValue": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.firstValue | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 18."
        ]
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get a response like

```cs
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|6ba7ef4a-442494fd16304f12.",
    "errors": {
        "$.firstValue": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.firstValue | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 18."
        ],
        "$.secondValue": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.secondValue | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 19."
        ]
    }
}
```

But I just can't figure out how to do that. I hope that my question was clear enough, otherwise please post a comment and I will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 3.0 ASP.NET Core uses `System.Text.Json` for handling JSON. It stops deserialization on the first error and there doesn't seem to be a setting for disabling it.

If you need more deserialization errors you can use old `Newtosoft.Json`. Just add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` nuget package and add change the following line in `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddControllers();
```

to

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

However, `System.Text.Json` has got better perforamnce and it's reccomended to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that explains why I couldn't find a solution to the issue. I do want to use System.Text.Json so hopefully they will add an option for this in the future.